# React: Adding two arrays (with the same variable name) into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I know adding two arrays together is a rookie situation, but here we are.

**Issue/Challenge**:
The thing I'm struggling with is that both arrays have the same variable name, `data`, yet I need to add them.

Let me explain.
I'm doing two queries:

- One for `graphQL`, and
- another from an API using the `useQuery` hook.

However, it seems that both queries require the name `data` and complains if it's anything different. I've tried the following:

- `data.push(data)`,
- `data.concat(data)`,
- `const combinedData = [...data, ...data]`

And now I'm knocking on your door for advice.

Here's my code:

```js
const Lesson: FC<PageProps<LessonByIdQuery, { locale: string }>> = ({
  //QUERY 1
  data,
  pageContext: { locale },
  location: { pathname },
}) => {
  const {
    nextLesson,
    previousLesson,
    contentfulLesson: {
      lessonName: title = "",
      lessonContent: content,
      slug,
      createdAt,
      updatedAt,
      cover,
      keywords,
      authorCard,
      additionalInformation: readMore,
      habit: habits,
    },
  } = data as {
    contentfulLesson: ContentfulLesson
    nextLesson: ContentfulLesson
    previousLesson: ContentfulLesson
  }

  // QUERY 2
  // FetchLessonBookmark IS IMPORTED
  const { data, status } = useQuery("lessonTemplateKey", FetchLessonBookmark)
```

My goal from all of this is to combine the data from the queries and then map out what I need. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alias the variable name to something else. Refer: https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-alias

Comment: This should help `const { data: lesson, status } = useQuery("lessonTemplateKey", FetchLessonBookmark)` where `data` is renamed as `lesson` variable. Can you try that?

Comment: I tried that yesterday and it worked. :)